# minimum number of unit distances required for a unit equilateral triangle

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, combinatorial-geometry

> **Problem.** Suppose we have $n$ points on the plane. Among $\binom{n}{2}$ pairwise distances, there are $e$ number of unit
>   distances. Find minimum $e$ ($e$ as a function of $n$) so that there is a equilateral triangle
>   with unit sides.

The problem is a generalization of Mexico 1995 National Olympiad Problem 2 posted on AOPS [here](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=41&t=599400)

Comment: If $n$ points are placed on the $x$-axis at integer points, there will be $n-1$ unit distances and we do not have an equilateral triangle. But, we do not have "all" unit distances. (By the time I typed this comment, I could no longer see vadim's comment to which I intended to reply.)

Comment: If $n=m^2$ points are put in a square grid, we can have $2m(m-1)=2n-2\sqrt{n}$ unit distances without a unit equilateral triangle.